# Why is the sentence "Please keep the area clean and well organize." incorrect?

Tags: sentence-construction, teaching

I am a tutor working with a student who has made this sentence. I am trying to explain why we shouldn't say "well organize" why we should say "well organized." I have explained it in several different ways but nothing is working.

Comment: How have you already tried explaining it? It would help the folks that might answer your question to know what you've already tried so that they don't waste your time and theirs.

Comment: Did you start with the verb, **to organize {something}**?

Comment: Thank you for the info so far. I gave her examples of "organize" in a sentence.  I explained that if something is "well organized " it is organized in a good way and that if something is "not well organized" it is still organized but not in a good way. I'm trying to show that the sentence doesn't mean the same thing if she uses "well organize"

Answer (score 1):

Organized can be used as an adjective. I think it's easy to get through the grammar of *keep something + adjective*.

Then you can explain *to organize something*. It's *to organize the area* in this context. So the area is **being organized**. The passive should be used. On the other hand, *organized* also connotes that the area has been organized already and we suggest keeping it staying organized. That's why *keep the area organized*.

You can also use the analogy. Give some examples which your student is familiar with. That would be very helpful I think. For example, *keep this problem unattended*.

Hope this can help a bit.